# Can I create a class inside other class? and call all together

Tags: c++, class

im newbie in c++ so I hope you can help me in this.

i have this class Appearances, i show a bit of the code of the cpp

```
Appearances::Appearances(const char* id, float shininess,const char* textureref)
{this->id = id;
setShininess(shininess);
this->textureref = textureref;
}
```

and i want to join another class "Component" like this

```
Component(float ambient[4] , float diffuse[4] , float specular[4])
    {setAmbient(ambient);
    setDiffuse(diffuse);
    setSpecular(specular);
    }
```

And what I want is that i can call appearances with all of this joined, for example:

```
app = new Appearances(idAppearance, vAmb, vDif, vSpec, shininess, txtRef);
```

im trying to get this on c++

```
<appearance id="app1" shininess="6.0" textureref="ss" >
           <component type="ambient" value="5 5 5 5" />
           <component type="diffuse" value="5 5 5 5" />
           <component type="specular" value="0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6" />
    </appearance>
```

I dont know if I explained well what i want, but can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you would need to change your constructor to include the data of the component class.

```
Appearances::Appearances(const char* id,float ambient[4] , float diffuse[4] , float specular[4], float shininess,const char* textureref)
```

Then in the constructor you call the constructor of Component.

But this raise the question of design.  If you can initialize your component, it means it just a logical group you want to do, i suggest to use nomenclature instead like comp_Ambient.

If you want to be able to have more than one component in your class, then you don't want to initialize it in the constructor.

The other reason I see to use this design, is being able to use component on other object, then, don't put it in the class.

Comment: Will your components only be float[4] ?

Comment: Then I suggest you to use a map for the component

Answer (score 0):

Do you need full access to components members and functions? If so, I see two possible answers to your question. The simplest way would be to create a derived class which inherits from both Appearances and Component. For example, you could declare `class Design: public Appearances, public Component`. While multiple inheritance can sometimes complicate design, it seems to be the most straightforward option. See more [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/multiple_inheritance.html).

If you would like to add the functionality to the existing Appearances class, this can be done by making Component a friend class of Appearances. This is done by adding the line `friend class Appearances;` to your Component class, which allows Appearances to access all members of Component. In this case, you will also need to declare two constructors: one for initializing Appearances without Component, and one for initializing Appearances with the data for Component.

Comment: Component is a part of Appearances, I have to acess this:
<appearance id="app1" shininess="6.0" textureref="ss" >
      <component type="ambient" value="5 5 5 5" />
      <component type="diffuse" value="5 5 5 5" />
      <component type="specular" value="0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6" />
        </appearance>